# why my wordpress project not working in public ip address?

Tags: wordpress

I developed a website in wordpress and it is not displayed over public IP address.What do  I need to do to solve the issue?
What might be reasons for the problem?
Thanks

Comment: what error it throws? code 500? 
If so, check file permissions and/or ownership

Comment: Error 404: Not Found

Comment: please share url here if possible

Answer (score 0):

In case of error 404, issue is in most cases related with permalinks.

You need to rebuild permalinks, go to  **/wp-admin/options-permalink.php** and resave settings, it will flush rewrite settings in .htaccess and db and 
rebuild new one.

If you have wp cli, try using command: 
`wp rewrite flush` within main directory of your WordPress site.

See: 
**https://wp-cli.org/commands/rewrite/flush/**

Comment: What to change in settings in options-permalink.php?

Comment: nothing to change in options-permalink.php file, never change core files, but go that path in while in admin ( Settings > Permalinks )